# Loading Files from a Directory in Haskell

Tags: haskell, file-system, monads

I'm a very new Haskell programmer, and I've written the following code for loading TSV files. I think it can be improved, but I'm not sure how.

1. I feel like the giant "do" block in loadData is inelegant, and that there's likely a better way to approach this.
2. I think I'm trying to avoid the IO monad because I'm not sure how to work with it, but that there's probably a better way to handle mapping `parseTSV` over the contents of the files.

One note: I'm not super concerned about performance - this will run once at the beginning of my program. I want to load in all the files entirely to build a composite data structure from their contents.

```
module LanguageMachine (loadData) where

import System.Directory (listDirectory)
import Data.List ((\\), elemIndex)
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

parseTsv :: String -> [(String, Int)]
parseTsv contents = mapMaybe parseLine (lines contents)

parseLine :: String -> Maybe (String, Int)
parseLine line =
    case elemIndex '\t' line of
        Just i ->
            let
                (word, count) = splitAt i line
            in
                Just (word, read count :: Int)
        Nothing -> Nothing

loadData :: FilePath -> [FilePath] -> IO [(String, [(String, Int)])]
loadData path exclude = do
    files <- listDirectory path
    let filtered = files \\ exclude
    let prefixed = map ((path ++ "/") ++) filtered
    contents <- traverse readFile prefixed
    let results = map parseTsv contents
    return $ zip filtered results
```

The files look like this, which are two-value TSV lines of a word and then the number of occurrences of that word:

```
ARIA    4308
ORE 4208
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `loadData` function looks just fine to me. I don't see a way it could be any more elegant given what it's doing. I do actually like the way you have separated reading the file and parsing it. That's the way to go.

Your concern about "avoiding the IO monad" shouldn't be a concern. On the contrary, that's actually a "best practice", known as "pushing I/O to the boundary". It means that the majority of your program should be pure, and only a thin shell should deal with external world. This way you can easily test and debug the majority of your program.

The only thing I might do is make the last three lines one expression:

```
traverse readFile prefixed
  <&> map parseTsv
  <&> zip filtered
```

I find this a bit more readable, but that's just a matter of personal taste.

---

But the `parseLine` function could sure use some improvement.

**First,** the control flow. Look what it's doing: compute a `Maybe` value, then if it's `Just`, compute another `Maybe` value from its contents. That's exactly what "bind" does! This means it can be nicely represented as a `do` block.

**Second,** `read` is a partial function. This means it can fail at runtime if there is a non-number in the file. I understand this probably Should Never Happen™, but you'd be surprised how many things that "should never happen" do, in fact, happen all the time. :-)

But since you're already in the `Maybe` context, it would be easy to use [`readMaybe`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.5/base-4.13.0.0/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) instead, and skip the malformed numbers.

Applying both points:

```
parseLine line = do
    i <- elemIndex '\t' line
    let (word, strCount) = splitAt i line
    count <- readMaybe strCount
    return (word, count)
```

Comment: Thank you! The <&> operator is very handy. I'm still getting comfortable thinking in monads, so your feedback is very helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help!